# Server.MapPath in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, server.mappath

I have developed a Web Application using `ASP.Net` with `Microsoft Access` as database. Now i have connected to the database using OleDB connection. The problem is when i give the database source in Connection String `Source="C:/WebApp/DB/data.mdb"`. The connection throws an error stating the path is invalid and there is no such file.

I tried using

```
Server.MapPath("~/DB/data.mdb")
```

which gives the path as "C:/WebApp/DB/data.mdb" but throws the same error

```
Colud not locate file 'C:/WebApp/DB/data.mdb'
```

What should be the problem, even though if it works good in loalhost when i publish it to the server using Plesk, it shows the same error stating "C:/inetpub/xyx.com/httpdocs/..." not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the wndows path (backslash rather than forward slash).

If you are shipping an access database with a web application, you can also investigate putting it in the App_Data folder. Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx) for more info.

A fully worked example is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/445z2s49%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Note that in your current example, if DB is a folder under the web root, anyone could potentially download your database if they know the file name. By default, items stored in App_Data will NOT be served to clients.

Also note that, usefully, when you store the item in App_Data, your connection string becomes:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\data.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
```

(plus any user/password details). ASP.Net will resolve the |DataDirectory| path at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

did you try with the windows path? (note backslash)

```
C:\WebApp\DB\data.mdb
```

Answer (score 0):

There might have several problems, would you please check below items:

- Check the `DB` folder is exists at root level of your application
- Make sure the database file `data.mdb` is exist uder `DB` folder

Take appropriate action based on any option is missing as listed above.